# too many values to unpack runtime error python

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am getting an error that states too many values to unpack(expected 2)
Here is my code:

```
fin = open ('ride.in', 'r')
fout = open ('ride.out', 'w')
output=" "
for line in fin:
    line = line.lower()
    for character in line:
        number = ord(character) - 96
        output = output+str(number)+","
ufo,commet=output.split(",-86,")
ufolist = ufo.split(',')
commetlist= commet.split(',')
ufoproduct=1
commetproduct=1
for item in ufolist.items(): #(Line with error)
    ufoproduct = int(item)*ufoproduct
for item in commetlist.items(): #(This would probably have the same error)
    commetproduct=int(item)*commetproduct
if ufoproduct % 47 == commetproduct % 47:
    fout.write("GO")
    fout.close()
    else:
        fout.write("STAY")
    fout.close()
```

The ride.in has two lines of text

Comment: Presumably coming from `ufo,commet=output.split(",-86,")`

Comment: depends on the actual contents of `ride.in` but it seems like ",-86," occurs more than once in `output`

Comment: yes, this happens when the split matches more than once. Can you also post some example input? Also, I'd recommend you to use pep8 style to make your code more readable.

Comment: `ride.in` probably looks like it has two lines of text but I'd bet it has a trailing newline, which would be very significant to this script.

Comment: for line in fin.readlines():

Comment: The example input had a trailing newline. I fixed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would've helped to see an example of `ride.in` file, so that your error can be recreated. 
There's a problem with `ufolist = ufo.split(',')` - this gives you a list, which you're trying to treat as a `dict`. `for item in ufolist.items():` doesn't need the `.items()` part

Comment: Thanks, I will fix that. Also, the ride.in file probably has a trailing new line. How do I account for that?

Comment: Try `rstrip()`, so you'll have `line = line.rstrip().lower()`